# Permanently Bricked?

Tags: adb, samsung, twrp

I have a Samsung Galaxy s10e that is stuck in a boot loop. I have tried everything imaginable from a cache reset to a total reinstallation of Samsung flashed through Odin. Now, I want to try to install TWRP on it but I have run into several problems. The first problem is that the bootloader is locked, and like I said, I cannot boot the OS to unlock it. Second, ADB cannot connect because USB debugging is disabled. (I can get it to connect in Apply update from ADB) I have installed the Samsung USB drivers though and they worked with Odin.

I have tried to install TWRP with an SD card, but for some reason the files I want to use are not found in the Micro SD card. (I have both a .img and a .img.tar file in there)

I also used ADB update to try to install TWRP, but that failed because maybe the bootloader is locked??? Thanks for your help.

Later: I tried factory data resetting it again and resetting the cache partition and it actually got to the setup screen after several attempts. I then tried to get it set up enough to unlock the bootloader and enable the usb debugging, but it would always crash before I got there. When it crashes, it freezes for 10 seconds then restarts. Also if you are wondering, there is not Samsung charging screen with the battery percentage when you plug it in when it is powered off.

Comment: Have you tried to boot into safe mode? TWRP is only on option if the bootloader is unlocked.

Comment: First you should handle the boot-loop, try to reinstall the official ROM, and plz make sure it's the correct model